# Dealing with provocative questions in interview from higher management third level above oneself

Tags: interviewing

How to prepare for provocative less formal but allowed and unexpected questions? Like, they establish a positive warm bond and feeling and then try to destabilize.

Example:

- Tell us which negative things would your friends/colleagues tell about you?

Comment: @gnat I miss the parth there in the STAR technique that previously a warm bond is established.

Comment: Can you give some example questions, so we have an idea what kind of "provocative" things are asked?

Comment: @J.Doe On the "not-so-bad" scale it's STAR technique, etc. On the more "scary" scale like you mention if it is to establish a wam bond and then get under your skin, these can be sociopathic/ psychopathic techniques eg. NLP, and so on. Research NLP (it's very negative in my view) as well as Stefan Verstappen. There may or may not be something deeper going on here.

Answer (score 0):

> Dealing with provocative questions in interview from higher management third level above oneself

The same way you deal with the rest.

Prepare thoroughly for an interview in terms of discussing your skills and experience professionally and don't get deeply involved with anything else.

If you don't understand the motivation behind a question or the question itself, don't answer it until you have clarification.

Comment: motivation in context of the question: "try to destabilize". So just ignore is your answer or ask why they ask this?

Comment: @J.Doe no you don't ignore anything, you ask for clarification. But not clarification of their motivation, clarification of the question. You can only be destabilised if you're unstable.